# "unable to open database file" in django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with sqlite3 in django. This is the first time I'm using this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/home/djangobook/mydb.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self._sqlite_create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in _sqlite_create_connection
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you already run syncdb?

Comment: hi dear. No , what is this?

Comment: Are you running this as user djangobook? Do you have write access to the given path?

Comment: @user1788781 syncdb is the command to create the database in your application folder at the same level than manage.py run this in console: python manage.py syncdb

Comment: yes , I have write access to given path.

Comment: python manage.py syncdb --->> "OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Comment: @user1788781 Version of django and python please?

Comment: python: 2.7.4
django: 1.5.4

Comment: Is there any idea? :)

Comment: I have root access :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't run [syncdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-syncdb)

Into your application folder at the same level than manage.py run this in console:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

For better understanding of django, follow this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) by the way you have to write access to the folder.

Comment: thank you but it's result : python manage.py syncdb --->> "OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Answer (score 3):

You need write access to the /home/djangobook/ directory and to the /home/djangobook/mydb.db file (is exists).

If the /home/djangobook/mydb.db file does not exist you need to run python manage.py syncdb as pointed by @user1788781.

Comment: thank you but it's result :
python manage.py syncdb --->> "OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Comment: Ok, so be sure thet the /home/djangobook/ directory exists and your user has write access to /home/djangobook/.

Comment: I have root access :(

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer from me because there is one other possibility which hit me while playing with a Graphite deployment (graphite's web UI is httpd+django). 
Even if you have the full path configured, permissions are ok on both the db file and the directory, you might have Selinux Enforcing.

If you need selinux enforcing, sorry, I cannot provide details right now on how to make this setup work, but if it is accidentally enabled just do :

```
root # getenforce
Enforcing
root # setenforce 0
root # getenforce
Permissive
```

One tip, to debug this issue deeper and confirm it is an issue related to permissions you could use `strace`  :

```
$ sudo service httpd stop
$ sudo strace -f service httpd start 2>&1 | tee tmp.log

# strace log could contain something similar to the following:
$ grep mydb.db tmp.log 
.... stat("/home/djangobook/mydb.db", 0x7fff55023b80) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
.... open("/home/djangobook/mydb.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```